# Change username color in Terminal on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal

I've looked everywhere and can't find anything. How do I change the color of this whole line in the terminal?

`user@MacBook-Pro ~ %`

Comment: Have you tried changing font colors in Preferences/Profile?

Comment: do these tips work on the Mac? https://askubuntu.com/questions/123268/changing-colors-for-user-host-directory-information-in-terminal-command-prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following line in my .bash_profile file that changes font colors. it appears to do what you want but it changes colors in several places.  Doing

> ls -lrt

show changes to all the font colors. I don't understand the line but maybe one part of it effects only the line you want.

> export PS1="[\033[36m]\u[\033[m]@[\033[32m]\h:\$ "

Comment: To change the color I used `export PS1="\033[36m\u$ "`

Answer (score 23):

I tried all solutions above, but none of them work with new ZSH terminal on MacOS, so, I discover a new solution.

1. open terminal e go to the user folder with: `cd ~`;
2. create a new file called `.zshrc` with: `touch .zshrc`;
3. open the file with VI: `vi .zshrc`;
4. enter in the edit mode: `press I key`;
5. paste the following code with `CMD + V`:

```sh
NEWLINE=$'\n'
DATE=$( date +"[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]" )
PROMPT="${NEWLINE}%F{yellow}${DATE} %(!.%F{red}.%F{white})%n%F{cyan}@%m %F{yellow}%d${NEWLINE}%F{reset}> "
```

6. quit of edit: `press ESC`;
7. save the changes and quit: `press :wq`;
8. close Terminal app and open again, you should see something like this:

[image]

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/549150/1127802

Comment: I confirm this worked on MacOS Catalina

Answer (score 5):

You can use this generator for customize your PROMPT - https://zsh-prompt-generator.site/

1. cd
2. nano .zshrc
3. Paste your PROMPT(example - PROMPT="%(!.%F{red}.%F{white})%n%F{cyan}@%m%F{yellow}%~$%F{reset}")
4. Save changes and reload terminal.